# How to filter a value from the request line of log

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have the following log and I need to filter only **salePoint** from it.

```
"GET /supero/global/grocery/fullgrainMenu.jsp?id=cat12216&salePoint=0012FT&locale=es_ES&version=0510091431 HTTP/1.1"
```

I tried `\"(%{NOTSPACE:request}(?:&salePoint=%{DATA:salePoint})?)\"` but it giving wrong output

```
"salePoint": "0012FT&locale=es_ES&version=0510091431 HTTP/1.1"
```

Expected output is `"salePoint": "0012FT`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question specified that the intention is to find and filter only **salePoint**, you can use the following grok pattern:

```
(%{GREEDYDATA:before})?(salePoint=%{WORD:salePoint})(%{GREEDYDATA:after})?
```

---

**Explanation** :

1. **before** : It stores the optional data before salePoint entry is found.
2. **salePoint** : this stores the salePoint value
3. **after** : It stores the optional data after salePoint.

As always you can use add more to the pattern if you need to filter out more fields.

---

**Example :**

```
"GET /supero/global/grocery/fullgrainMenu.jsp?id=cat12216&salePoint=0012FT&locale=es_ES&version=0510091431 HTTP/1.1"
```

With the above pattern output is :

```
{
  "before": [
    [
      ""GET /supero/global/grocery/fullgrainMenu.jsp?id=cat12216&"
    ]
  ],
  "salePoint": [
    [
      "0012FT"
    ]
  ],
  "after": [
    [
      "&locale=es_ES&version=0510091431 HTTP/1.1""
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Please use [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to play around with the pattern.